# How to change URL of query result page in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am creating a simple Dictionary using PHP and Mysql: whenever I query a word it display its meaning but its URL structure is not looking good.

Present URL structure is this: `http://127.0.0.1/search.php?query=Acromania`

And I want this URL structure: `http://127.0.0.1/Acromania` , of search result page.

Is there any way to do that in PHP?

Comment: No but with the help of Apache .htaccess file you can achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

No, for sure you need a .htaccess file for this process. Create .htaccess file in your working directory and put this code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Now if you are calling this URL http://127.0.0.1/Acromania apache automatically processing your query like a charm.

**Make sure you have enabled `mod_rewrite` on your apache.

Comment: I enabled mod_rewrite and added your given code in .htaccess file, but id doesn't work.